# The strange syntax of a C debug macro

Tags: c, syntax

Can anyone explain to me the C-syntax below (from this [tutorial](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex20.html))? I understand this is a macro for C, but the  "DEBUG %s:%d: " M "\n"
part seems strange to me: why is there the macro parameter 'M' in the middle of the format part?

```
#define debug(M, ...) fprintf(stderr, 
            "DEBUG %s:%d: " M "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: That's fascinating! And cool! I like it!  I've never before seen a way to force parameters to be literals, but this is the trick!

Comment: there must be a backslash missing?

Comment: @MooingDuck: so you read this and, unlike the OP (and me), *immediately* grapsed it? That's quite a knack for C you got, mate.

Comment: @MooingDuck I have added a reference for the original code.

Comment: @Jongware: I recently added macros _very_ similar to this to several of my projects, so yes, I immediately recognized it.  Mine jump through hoops though, because I never thought of using string literal concatenation to modify the format string

Comment: @Jongware Back in my day stuff like this was commonplace... (except for `, ##__VA_ARGS__` which is a useful GCC extension)

Comment: @MooingDuck actually this "trick" is your only option if you want the user to be able to use format specifiers, so I'm curious as to what your debug macros looked like previously :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I'd `sprintf` the beginning to a buffer, then "concatenate" `sprintf` their format/parameters, then "concatenate" `sprintf` the ending, then send the buffer along.  Obviously all delegated to a function rather than all that being in the macro directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C has an interesting quirk that it concatenates string literals.  If you type

```
"DEBUG %s:%d: " "HELLO %s!" "\n"
```

Then the compiler sees that as one string: `"DEBUG %s:%d: HELLO %s!\n"`.  So users can use this macro as if it were simply had printf parameters:

```
debug("HELLO %s", username); //on line 94 of myfile.cpp
```

and the macro will automatically add the file name and line number.  This format is useful because it helps you know *which* debug statement is logging information.

```
DEBUG myfile.cpp:94: HELLO zell
```

Answer (score 3):

`debug("This should never happen!");`

evaluates to

`fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG %s:%d: " "This should never happen!" "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)`

Which concatenates to...

`fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG %s:%d: This should never happen!\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)`

So it prints something like...

`DEBUG foo.c:51: This should never happen!`

Answer (score 2):

Strings are joined together automatically in C.  "Hello " "World!" is the same as "Hello World!".

```
DEBUG("An error occurred opening file %s", filename)
```

Expands to:

```
fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG %s:%d:  An error occurred opening file %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, filename)
```

Which I think you'll agree is pretty handy and the right result.